# Spring boot not able to read custom @Query annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have requirement when we apply @CustomQUery annotation, then I need to intercept this method and append the query predicate which I already know.

Created

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Documented
public @interface CustomQuery {
    
    Query query();

}

@Repository
public interface FloorRepository extends JpaRepository<TnFloor, Integer> {
    
    public String query="select distinct tnFloor from TnFloor tnFloor where tnFloor.tnBuilding.buildingId in ?1 ";
    
    
    @CustomQUery(query=@Query(query))
    public List<TnFloor> findByBuildingIds(List<Integer> buildingIds);

}
```

Here, Spring is unable to read this @CustomQUery because I have not mentioned anywhere to read this annotation.

Is this the correct way to create custom query annotation ?

I am getting below exception on application startup.

```
  Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List 
 FloorRepository.findByBuildingIds(java.util.List)! 
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List  FloorRepository.findByBuildingIds(java.util.List)! 
No property buildingIds found for type TnFloor! 
Did you mean 'buildingId'?;
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to c
```

Comment: Why would you do this? I guess you could plugin some code generation that replaces your custom annotation with the proper Spring Data annotation, but why?

Comment: Cant you just use `@Query`?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have already said in comments, I think your way of extending the Query annotation is usefull only if you need to do some things more than just extending it.

If you need some paths to enhance the behavior of the `@Query` annotation, maybe using `@Modifying` annotation could get the point, or using `@NamedQuery` and `@NamedNativeQuery` annotations too.

If it is a requirement you could not resolve with these other annotations, maybe make some click on them to see how they are declared and raised in the Spring IoC ecosystem using Aspect programming.

The problem here, to my point of view, seems not to be related to your annotation, but a missing property, as the error message has told to you :

`No property buildingIds found for type TnFloor!  Did you mean 'buildingId'?;`

Maybe because of a typo error in your annotation when you are using it, which is not found :
declared as `public @interface CustomQuery` and used as `@CustomQUery(query=@Query(query))`. Write the things as they are declared will work better I think.

Did you try using native query feature like that too ?

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname FROM Author a"); 
// of course, update with your own code.
```

You can look at [what JPA is capable of](https://thorben-janssen.com/query-complex-jpa-hibernate/) and switch to native query as I have just added if it is not supported.

Comment: This does not work.

I am thinking to acheive this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353427/spring-not-picking-updated-query-value-using-aop

Comment: It is curious that NamedNativeQuery is not able to do a nested query. Updated my answer here with some code in few minutes. Updated now.